# What lasts longer: the Cheesburger or a perception of it?

Tags: vipassana

What lasts longer: the Cheesburger or a perception of it?

[image]

What's more real? Where to put into de-veloping?

Comment: This question "What lasts longer: the Cheeseburger or a perception of it?" will last longer than both the cheeseburger and the perception of it.

Comment: I see so many user accounts by the same name. Any reason why?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille He has said that he doesn't want to register an account, because an account is "not offered" and also perhaps because he disapproves of this site. With an unregistered account, the account depends on cookies in the device's browser (instead of depending on the user's email address), and a new account is created every time he clears the device's cookies (which is frequently).

Answer (score 3):

Asking what is real or not is a worthless question clung to by philosophers. The suttas say:

> I will not engage in talk that is base, vulgar, common, ignoble,
>   unbeneficial, that does not lead to disenchantment, dispassion,
>   cessation, calm, direct knowledge, self-awakening, or Unbinding —
>   i.e., talk about kings, robbers & ministers of state; armies, alarms,
>   & battles; food & drink; clothing, furniture, garlands, & scents;
>   relatives; vehicles; villages, towns, cities, the countryside; women &
>   heroes; the gossip of the street & the well; tales of the dead; tales
>   of diversity, the creation of the world & of the sea; **talk of whether
>   things exist or not**.' In this way he is alert there.
>
> MN 122

The questions the Lord Buddha asked about cheeseburgers were:

1. Are cheeseburgers permanent or impermanent?
2. Do cheeseburgers bring lasting happiness or are they unsatisfactory?
3. Should cheeseburgers be regarded as 'This is mine. This is my self. This is what I am'?.

Comment: Hmm. Asking what is real led me to Buddhism so the idea that the question worthelss is not plausible to me. Once one is one the path then it may become worthless, but only because following the path is the way to answer the question. I feel the Buddha's advice for practitioners is not meant for sceptics and waverers.

Comment: My impression of Buddha is he was concerned with "real happiness". Kind regards

Comment: Your impression? Mine too. But why denigrate philosophers and their questions? After all, Buddhist teachings answer them. .

Comment: You seem to be inferring Samana Johann is a philosopher?

Comment: @Dhammadhatu I think Peter is inferring that he himself is a philosopher -- and that you seem to be "denigrating" philosophers and philosophy.

Comment: Yes. That's it. I cannot grasp how asking what is real can be a worthless activity, especially as it is likely to lead people to Buddhism. .

Comment: @PeterJ I think the early suttas (i.e. pre-Nagarjuna) have a theme of accepting only certain questions as being useful -- see e.g. [The unanswered questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_unanswered_questions) ... the [Parable of the Poisoned Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Poisoned_Arrow) ... the [Simsapa Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.031.than.html) ... also some concepts like "empty speculation is a fetter". I guess "real" comes from a "real..ideal" philosophical split (duality), or "subjective..objective"?

Comment: Without wanting to be rude to philosophers, I admire what I understand to have been the Buddha's attitude, his "solution" to that (that kind of) "problem" -- it reminds me of the famously incisive Gordian Knot solution, i.e. to dismiss or undo the problem.

Comment: @ChrisW  Yes, I get this. My point is that whether a question is useful depends on  who we are and what stage we're at. The Buddha spoke to an audience.of monks, For most people asking what is real would be one the most valuable things they could do. The alternative is to settle for naive realism. ,.

Comment: @PeterJ Personally in the past I found naive or inept introductions to Buddhism -- not Nagarjuna's, but modern paraphrases -- "X isn't real" or "X doesn't really exist" -- to be just confusing or patronising or other-worldly. So I'm grateful to have been introduced since then to the texts of the suttas, which I find relatively practical and prescriptive,

Comment: @Chris - I see what you're saying. But these sayings need not be confusing in metaphysics. They mean that X must be reduced for a fundamental theory.  Thus we could say (with the physicists)  that pianos don't really exist. An understanding of dependent-existence depends on seeing that a dependent-existent does not really exist - is composite, without substance etc., and although this is best learned 'empirically' it may also be discussed in theoretical terms and the logic examined and tested, as the Buddha advises when we are sceptical.       .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94386/discussion-between-chrisw-and-peterj).

Answer (score 2):

asking what is real or not is a worthless question clung to by philosophers addicted to rupa who fail to see that the other aggregates are more important.

What matters is what you do with vedana, sanna, vinnana, rupa and sankharas, ie to view them with sati, right view, panna and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Cheeseburger is nama pannatti. Ideas about a particular cheeseburger is santhana pannatti. The physical cheeseburger is dathu which lasts only momentarily. Pannatti lasts longer than the object itself as it is not subjected to 3 characteristics as they are not real. So the pannatti lasts longer. The sanna about the cheeseburger lasts only momenterity and lasts much shorter. Same for the physical cheeseburger. Perception in your question can fit with both sanna and pannatti.

Comment: Sadhu so far Upasaka Sirinath. Let my person ask further: is pannati an aspect of nama or rupa, or both? Or in how far whould pannati not just sanna?